# DbContext, To Inject or To not Inject?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

This may well be a question with a million answers but it is bugging me a lot.

I have an mvc application using EF. Now do I inject the DbContext into my business objects or do I do it some other way?

I can obviously inject it but that way I end up using DbContext in my classes rather than a Typed Context. This means I have no intellisense and the code looks less graceful

eg

```
var test=(from d in context.Set<User>() where d.Username=="testname" select d).FirstOrDefault();
```

compared to the typed loveliness

```
var test=(from d in context.Users where d.Username=="testname" select d).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I know this is not a massive issue but when writing tens of thousands of lines it is nice to have intellisense around, especially if other coders not so familiar with the code are helping out.

I know there is the unit of work pattern but this is in my opinion the work of the devil himself when EF is involved as it is effectively wrapping a repository pattern in a repository pattern which is just ludicrous. So this is not an option for me.

So do we inject and if so can we somehow end up with a typed context?

Or do we not inject?

Comment: not sure what's ur problem. if u use the code generated dbcontext code, u should have the .Users .

Comment: Yes as in the second example. However if you use injection the DbContext base class has to be used rather than they generated one.

Comment: Please check this article: http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think there might be some misunderstanding in the term 'inject'.

Inject means this:

```
public class UserService
{
    MyContext _db;

    public UserService(MyContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void GetUserById(string id)
    {
        _db.Users.First(x => x.Id = id);
    } 
}
```

Instead of this:

```
public class UserService
{
    MyContext _db = new MyContext();

    public UserService()
    {
    }

    public void GetUserById(string id)
    {
        _db.Users.First(x => x.Id = id);
    } 
}
```

Notice how in the first example `MyContext` is 'injected' into the constructor. In the second example, `UserService` itself creates a new instance of `MyContext`.

Now, should you? I believe you should, and in fact, it is an accepted good practice. Before you do, make sure to read and try it on a few sample projects to find out the benefits it brings you. [Wikipidia: Dependency Injection Advantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Advantages)

Comment: Sorry, yes I am aware of what injection is (although I should have made that clear). However injection leads to a base class or interface having to be used (otherwise what would be the point?), Hence my question.

Comment: @coolblue2000 ah, I see the problem. No, 'injection' does not mean use base class. You can inject your 'typed' context no problem. The bigger conversation is 'should we depend on the concrete or on the abstraction?' That's a harder question :P

Comment: Yep, although it is possible to inject a concrete type, what would be the point as you are no better off than simply defining the concrete type as a non injected dependency....

Comment: @coolblue2000 There are still benefits for 'injecting' event without abstraction. For testing, you can still create 'test doubles', it also helps you manage object lifetime at a higher level, and creation of the objects is also something it can help with.